# Bootstrap HTML - Medium Sized Device Registers as Large

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, bootstrap-4

I've been running into some issues with Bootstrap's Grid on different devices. According to Bootstrap's documentation, column sizes in HTML are dependent on the device's window size. E.g.:

Extra small 576px ,  Small >= 768px ,    Medium >= 992px , Large >=1200px

However, in what should be considered a medium device (a rotated iPad that is 1024 x 768 on Google Chrome's Developer Tools) is being considered a Large Device by Bootstrap. My code looks like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
```

In landscape rotation, the iPad had the div at column size 2, which shouldn't be happening. I did a console log test to ensure the screen size, and it was indeed found to be 1024px. 
Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your math is slightly out of line with how Bootstrap calculates their breakpoint, confusing the **large** breakpoint (`>= 992px`) with the **extra large** breakpoint (`>= 1200px`).

While your iPad doesn't fall into the **extra** large breakpoint (which uses the `.col-xl-` prefix), it **does** fall into the **large** breakpoint (which uses the `.col-lg-` prefix), and thus the `.col-lg-2` class is correctly applied. Therefor your element takes up two columns.

See [the following image](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) for a handy list of breakpoints and their corresponding classes:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the help, it seems my problem was that I was following w3schools' documentation and not Bootstrap's. Now everything is working as it should.